# Android getBackground

Tags: android, button, kotlin, background

I am trying to have a button that if you click it, it sets the background but if the background is already set it does something else. Currently this is my code, but I can't seem to get it to work

```
if (view.background == R.drawable.frog) {
         //do stuff
} else {
         //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check null it if it null then its not set else background in already set.

```
if (view.background == null) {
     //do stuff
} else {
     //other stuff
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.frog)
if(view.background.constantState?.equals(drawable?.constantState) == true) {
     //do stuff
} else {
     //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
With Kotlin:

```
val bgAlready = btnTest.background.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.frog)?.constantState
            if (!bgAlready) {
                btnTest.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.frog)
            } else {
                //other stuff
            }
```

With Java:

```
boolean bgAlready = btnTest.getBackground().getConstantState() == 
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(TestActivity.this, R.drawable.frog).getConstantState();
                if (!bgAlready) {
                    btnTest.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(TestActivity.this, R.drawable.frog)); 
                } else {
                    //other stuff
                }
```